# How to remove all data by a suite name from UserDefaults in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, local-storage, nsuserdefaults

I have created user defaults with names below,

```
let prefs1 = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "UserAccount")
let prefs2 = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "UserInfo")
```

Then I have added some values to those suites. i.e.

```
prefs1.set(true, forKey: "Key1")
prefs1.set(true, forKey: "Key2")

prefs2.set(false, forKey: "Key1")
prefs2.set(false, forKey: "Key2")
```

Now, I want to remove the `prefs1` (i.e. name "UserAccount"), but not `prefs2`. I tried,

```
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: "UserAccount")
```

But it did not remove. I am getting confused with, `forName` and `suiteName`

How to remove a suite from `UserDefaults` keeping other suites intact in Swift?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56523845/1084174 did not help either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`func removePersistentDomain(forName domainName: String)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1417339-removepersistentdomain

> Calling this method is equivalent to initializing a user defaults
> object with init(suiteName:) passing domainName, and calling the
> removeObject(forKey:) method on each of its keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeSuite(named: "UserAccount")
```

If you want to just remove the keys. You can go for following

```
func removeAllFor(defaults: UserDefaults) {
        let dictionary = defaults.dictionaryRepresentation()
        dictionary.keys.forEach { key in
            defaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
        }
    }
```

Then you can call it on default that you want to clear data for

```
removeAllFor(defaults: prefs1)
```

removeSuite(named:) : Removes a sub-searchlist added via -addSuiteNamed method

removePersistentDomain(forName: ) : Removes all values from the search list entry specified by ‘domainName’.

Answer (score -1):

I usually a different approach that also cleans up keys, based in idea "nil = no more exisiting":

// make property:

```
   var userName: String? {

        set(NewValue) {
            self.setUserDefault(value: NewValue, for: USERNAME_KEY)
        }
        get{
            let v =  self.getFromUserDefaultsWith(key: USERNAME_KEY) as? String
            return v
        }
    }
```

// accessory functions: (here the trick)

```
private final func getFromUserDefaultsWith(key: String) -> Any? {
    let returnValue  = UserDefaults.standard.object( forKey: key)
    return returnValue
}

private final func setUserDefault(value: Any?, for key: String) {
    let ud = UserDefaults.standard
    if value == nil{
        ud.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }else{
        ud.set(value, forKey:  key)
    }
    ud.synchronize()
}
```

SO I can write:

```
final func wipeOut() {
    // if nil, we remove... see above.
    self.setUserDefault(value: nil, for: USERNAME_KEY)
}
```